# How to select records with distinct combination of 2 columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table as given below.

| Fare | City1 | City2 | Dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | B | 10 |
| 100 | B | A | 10 |
| 200 | A | C | 20 |
| 150 | B | D | 15 |
| 150 | D | B | 15 |

I want to select all records with a distinct combination of City1 and City2. Please note that A,B and B,A should be considered as same combination.

The desired output is as follows.

| Fare | City1 | City2 | Dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | B | 10 |
| 200 | A | C | 20 |
| 150 | B | D | 15 |

Thank you!

Comment: Can there be more than two rows with that pair of cities? Are you sure Fare and Dist will always be the same if you have two or more rows that are equivalent as your description? Which row do you want to be selected? The one with the least value in City1?

Comment: What if the distance or the fare is different in the other direction? Which value do you want reported in the output? This looks like a homework question rather than a real world problem.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to show what you tried, along with specific issue(s) that you're running into. As written, this is only a requirement with no effort shown.

Answer (score 1):

Force the order to always be the same, then select only the distinct rows.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  fare,
  IF(city1 < city2, city1, city2)  AS city1,
  IF(city1 < city2, city2, city1)  AS city2,
  dist
FROM
  your_table
```

Having noted the other answers, MySQL includes LEAST() and GREATEST(), allowing tidier code...

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  fare,
  LEAST(   city1, city2)  AS city1,
  GREATEST(city1, city2)  AS city2,
  dist
FROM
  your_table
```

Comment: OP showed no effort and only posted a requirement (possibly a school assignment?) - best not to answer when no work or specific question has been asked.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Your personal opinion on how I should carry on my own affairs is graciously noted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data with two combinations of each possible you could try

```
select fare, min(city1) city1, max(city2) city2, dist
from t
group by fare, dist;
```

Comment: This wouldn't return a row like (200, "B", "C", 20). The Fare, Dist combination may not be unique to the City1 City2 pair.

Comment: OP showed no effort and only posted a requirement (possibly a school assignment?) - best not to answer when no work or specific question has been asked.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer to this was too convoluted so I've removed it. See MatBaille's query to give the correct answer with neat SQL provided there is no 'bad data'. This question is a good advertisement for working with normalised data because there are too many alternative ways to handle 'bad data'.

To check for bad data, where Fare or Dist are different on different rows for the same unordered pair of cities, this shouldn't return any rows.

```
SELECT MAX(A.Fare) - MIN(A.Fare), LEAST(A.City1, A.City2) AS CityA, GREATEST(A.City1, A.City2) AS CityB, MAX(A.Dist) - MIN(A.Dist)
FROM FareTable A
GROUP BY CityA, CityB
HAVING (MAX(A.Fare) > MIN(A.Fare)) 
  OR (MAX(A.Dist) > MIN(A.Dist));
```

If it does, then the application reading from the SELECT DISTINCT... query will have to decide how to handle multiple rows with the same pair of cities.

Comment: The MIN(fare) and MIN(dist) are not necessarily from the same row, and so this pattern can behave "unexpectedly". Also, your second query groups by the cities Prior to ordering them with least and greatest, so I'm not convinced it does what you think it does.

Comment: If there's no 'bad data', then MIN(fare) and MIN(dist) should be equal to fare and dist respectively for all rows in the group. Can you provide an example of 'unexpected' behaviour? I ran my queries and haven't found issues yet at least.

Comment: Your SELECT DISTINCT query is neater (didn't know you could do that!), but I'll leave the answer posted because I think the other query could be of interest.

Comment: My query doesn't do the same thing as yours. We've interpretted the requirement differently.

Comment: My query will always return one row for distinct city1, city2 unordered pair. Yours can return more than one row if there's 'bad data'. But if not, I think they should return the same results.

Comment: Your third query may not do what you think it does.  It groups by `city1, city2` ***before*** the `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` have been applied.  This means that `A, B` and `B, A` do ***not*** get combined.

Comment: @MatBaille You're right that the cities aren't combined until after the grouping but the query works anyway because of the DISTINCT. Out of interest, I removed the DISTINCT and renamed the city1 and city2, without the B., to cityA and cityB then the query also works without the DISTINCT but returns city columns with different names from what was requested. I still think your query is the neatest and the application reading the results should have to deal with any 'bad data' it returns. Apart from my overly convoluted first query, I think my answer is of interest.

Comment: Then the GROUP BY is pointless. It only groups rows where the city order is already the same. Using both DISTINCT and GROUP BY is usually a code smell, as usually the same effect can be completed with just one, thus saving compute resources. https://dbfiddle.uk/PYlRnO4K

Comment: I've reworked my answer 'cos it was a mess. It is now just here to supplement MatBaille's answer. @MatBaille The GROUP BY ensured that duplicate City pairs wouldn't be returned so wasn't entirely pointless.

Comment: FYI comments are not for conversation and discussion (best to start a [chat] for something like this). Also, it's important to note that the OP showed *no work at all* - please refrain from answering questions that are nothing but a requirement (it is likely that this is some type of homework/classroom assignment that you are choosing to solve for them)